# iPhone and Ipad crashes:reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: objectid)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, crash

I am getting the following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: objectid)'
```

is it a dictionary or core data?I could not figure out where the crash is happening.Any idea?

```
2015-03-18 12:47:23.239 OneChannelApp[3039:6403] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:219): 2 hit(s) sent
2015-03-18 12:47:27.804 OneChannelApp[3039:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: objectid)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30668f83 0x3ae19ccf 0x305a48f3 0xbf357 0x32ea06df 0x3301643f 0x32f33d63 0x32f33b6d 0x32f33b05 0x32e85d59 0x32b0362b 0x32afee3b 0x32afeccd 0x32afe6df 0x32afe4ef 0x32af821d 0x30634255 0x30631bf9 0x30631f3b 0x3059cebf 0x3059cca3 0x354a2663 0x32ee914d 0x20555d 0x3b326ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: in your dictionary or array the key objected contains empty value. check the key contains empty or not after that add your object in that key

Comment: @Abhilash K M add exception breakpoint so that you will be getting the line where the exception occurs and also check your dictionary values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coredata error setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195878/coredata-error-setobjectforkey-object-cannot-be-nil)

Comment: Can it be core data?or dictionary?

Comment: Are you using core data?

Comment: yes i am using coredata

Comment: did you use breakpoint and checked on which line you are getting the exception

Comment: did you mean exception breakpoint? i dont know how to use it

Comment: i have updated the question.please look

Comment: see below i have posted how to give exception breakpoint

Comment: just go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: Thank you @Sunehachowdary ...adding exception breakpoint worked for me to find the crash.

Comment: Read the exception, it suggests where it crashed

Comment: fine.where you are getting exception

Comment: while adding object to a dictionary using setobject method.

Comment: @AbhilashKM just post ur code..i think you have resolved your issue right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more likely an `NSDictionary` error. And as it says, you are setting an object as `nil`.

Also, aren't you getting a line number or trace for the error?

Comment: This is the first line in the error. You must have copied it from the xCode console. Paste the lines underneath it, the whole chunk. Somewhere there it shows the line number as well or the class/function where it was called from.

Comment: just go to navigator area in that click on, from last second one and in that navigator down you will be getting + symbol click it and select on ADD Exception Breakpoint and now run it

Comment: You are not running the code directly from xCode, right? Because it shows you the error details in binary code form. \

Comment: @Sunehachowdary thanks for pointing that out. If it was an answer, I would have upvoted it. I am going to look at your other answers and upvote there :D

Comment: @iosDev82 i'm having doubt in my app and i have posted it but no one is answering .please can you help me....See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071612/getting-a-saved-video-from-document-directory-to-view-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

Its a NSDictionay crash because the code data can save value nil value..
its a error of trying to save nil value in NSDictionay...

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the solutions posted here and non resolved my issue. In the end it was an iOS simulator problem. In Xcode I had added a test GPS location by using:
Features - Location -> Custom Location...

I copy/pasted GPS locations which I obtained from maps.google.com so the locations should have been usable by the simulator. Note I had already tried Device -> Erase All Content and Settings, but this doesn't reset any simulated device location.

I was never specifically calling setObjectForKey: in any of my code. That appears to have been happening inside the CoreLocation library due to a bad value provided by the simulator at runtime.

The issue was resolved after I cleared out the lat and long gps values for simulated location.

I probably could have also discovered this if I had tested on an actual device.

Comment: So what was your solution? You don't actually explain how you fixed the issue calling `setObjectForKey:` with a nil value.

Comment: @HangerRash, I have updated my answer.

Comment: You still do not state the solution. How did you fix the error?